# how to communicate between embedded shiny app and html table in parent page

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have a webpage that allows the users to get data from a database. Then I use javascript to display the results in an interactive table (sorting, filtering). Now I embedded a shiny app in that page. I looked at articles like this one [Communicate between R and JS](https://unleash-shiny.rinterface.com/shiny-intro.html) that explains how to use javascript in shiny apps and communicate with the UI created by the app. But I can't figure out how to use javascript in the parent page to send data from the table in the parent page to the embedded shiny app. Ideally I would like to have my javascript code to fill the html table and then send the same data directly to the embeded shiny app. Is that possible ?  If not, can the shiny app grab the values from the parent page table directly ?

Comment: I found a solution. please let me know if there is a best way. What I did is use postMessage() to send the date to the iframe. Form there in the R app I used javascript and Shiny.setInputvalue() to send the object as a Json file to R and then used observeEvent to catch the input changes and start the R analysis of the data.